# Payment Module in Drupal9

Tags: php, module, drupal, payment-gateway, drupal-9

I am trying to install and enable payment method "Authorize.net" in my Drupal9 project but after installing module, it is disabled by default and I don't know how can I enable it for usage.
[it is module that I've installed, but I'm unable to click the check box to install it and use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5OxI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It had some modules that were not installed. Make sure to install all the required modules to enable authorize.net module.
The required modules were: Payment, Currency, PluginCredit, Field
[this details should not show any (required) module in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRJBt.png)